# Access Office365 SharePoint with Single Sign-On via Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, single-sign-on

I don't know much of anything about SharePoint, but was tasked to use Python to download a SharePoint list.  SharePoint is Office365 and is accessed with Single Sign-on.  I found the below sample on how to connect to SharePoint:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
ctx = ClientContext('https://<site>.sharepoint.com').with_credentials(UserCredential('domain\\user', 'password'))
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print(web.properties["Url"])
```

When executing this code I receive the following error:

```
Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf
KeyError: 'FedAuth'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Recently when I was searching for similar kind of solution, I found something useful, you can check below code on github.

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client

Comment: I tried implementing the samples there.  I'm receiving a similar error:

"An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS50006: Signature verification failed because of an invalid signature.
An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies from https://<site>.sharepoint.com"/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/